# What does the gesture Tony does to Agent Grasso mean?

Tags: the-sopranos

In the Soprano's Season One episode 8, Tony says something to Agent Grasso in Italian and makes a gesture with his hands.

He does it here in Season One episode 8 to which Grasso responds,

> Your Ass!!!!

And again in Season One episode 13;

[image: Sopranos FBI scene]

### So what does all this mean? What was the insult?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This insult looks like the [sign language of a woman's vagina](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vulva-handsign-Yoni-mudra.svg).

[image: gesture]

In the sign, the fingers are supposed to be joined, but as he says

> Ti faccio il culo cosi!

which means : "**I will make your ass** [large] **like this!**", the gesture is wider and the fingers don't touch.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but I was hoping for a definitive translation. +1 from me though.

Comment: He also says something in what I am assuming is Italian, along with knowing what he said should give a better understanding of what that gesture means.

Comment: @KyloRen: I didn't want to be too much explicit, but since you ask: it's a sexual obsene provocation. Tony insults agent Grasso by telling him he will sodomize his ass until it become large "like this" (also implying he has a very large penis). I hope it's clear now :-)